# Holding a Value in Unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a Question for you guys.I have 2 unit tests which are calling webservices .The value that one unit-test returns should be used for another unit test method

Example

```
namespace TestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        String TID = string.empty;

        public void test1
        {
           //calling webservices and code

           Assert.AreNotEqual(HoID, hID);
           TID = hID;
        }

        public void test2
        {
           //calling webservices and code            
           string HID = TID  // I need the TID value from the Above testcase here

           Assert.AreNotEqual(HID, hID);            
        }
    }
}
```

How can i store a value in one unittest and use that value in another unittest.

Comment: That's technically an integration test, unit tests should not depend on external influences (in your case a web service)

Comment: Typically, you don't want one unit test to depend on another, because you can't always trust the order the tests are run in, and it prevents you from being able to run one test at a time.

Comment: @trevor pilley yes.. but even in the integration testing how we can use a value returned by one unittest in another one...

Comment: @MikeRichards So how can we handle that situation...?? any ideas ??

Comment: If you are treating this as an integration test where you depend on one thing of which the output is passed to another, just merge the methods into one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't write your tests like this. You cannot ensure that your tests will run in any particular order, so there's no nice way to do this.

Instead make the tests independent, but refactor the common part into it's own (non-test) method that you can call as part of your other test.

Comment: This is the best route. Even better to inject a service-interface that returns known-testable values for your unit tests, and then test the service independently.

Comment: In terms of an integration test, this is the route I'd take, too. It means that when the first fails, both fails, but hey, you can't have all. Another possibility is to have a known token of which you are sure that it elicits the correct reaction from your test system, and use that on the second test.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reuse any values. Order in which tests are run is very often random (most common runners like NUnit's and Resharper's run tests in random order, some might even do so in parallel). Instead, simply call web service again (even if that means having *2* web service calls) in your second test and retrieve the value you need.

Each test (whether it's unit or integration) should have all the data/dependencies available for it to run. You should never rely on other tests to setup environment/data as that's not what they're written for.

Think of your tests in **isolation** - each single test is a separate being, that sets up, executes, and cleans up all that is necessary to exercise particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example, following the outlines of Oleksi, of how you could organize this

```
String TID = string.empty;

[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void Given() {
  //calling webservices and code
  TID = hID;
  //calling webservices and code
}

[Test]
public void assertions_call_1() {
   ...
}

public void assertions_on_call_2() {
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TID))
     Assert.Inconclusive("Prerequisites for test not met");
   ...
}
```

Comment: Makes sense!!!but what if every test has different data to call!! i am in that situation.Test 1 Create a Process, Test 2 deletes a process

Comment: @user1410658: *create-delete* is your integration process scenario then - this should be one test.